# Order of declaring config classes in SpringApplicationConfiguration. Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have such Spring Boot test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {
    PropertyConfig.class,
    ServiceConfigA.class,
    ServiceConfigB.class}
)
public class SpringTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
    ...
    }
}
```

When `PropertyConfig` class declared first in list of classes I get context initialization error because beans inside `PropertyConfig` ignored and beans from service configs can't autowire some fields. When I move `PropertyConfig` after some of serivce configs then beans inside `PropertyConfig` initialized.

In more details, `PropertyConfig` contains two beans: `PropertiesFactoryBean` and `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. Cause of `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` doesn't exist beans from service configs couldn't autowired fields with `@Value` annotation (can't automatic convert from String to Integer).

My question is why beans from `PropertyConfig` don't initialized in first case? 
Are there some features of config loading in Spring Boot tests?

Comment: Did my tip to make your `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` beans `static` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Spring scans dependencies registered into CI container and figures out order of their initialization. Order you are referring to is not relevant at all.

If it's failing for you, there has to be other some problem in your wiring. But you didn't show us your code, so hard to tell root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the "BeanFactoryPostProcessor-returning @Bean methods" section of the Javadoc for `@Bean`:

> Special consideration must be taken for @Bean methods that return
>   Spring BeanFactoryPostProcessor (BFPP) types. Because BFPP objects
>   must be instantiated very early in the container lifecycle, they can
>   interfere with processing of annotations such as @Autowired, @Value,
>   and @PostConstruct within @Configuration classes. To avoid these
>   lifecycle issues, mark BFPP-returning @Bean methods as static. For
>   example:
>
> ```
>  @Bean
>  public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc() {
>      // instantiate, configure and return ppc ...
>  }
> ```
>
> By marking this method as static, it can be invoked without causing instantiation of its declaring @Configuration class, thus
>   avoiding the above-mentioned lifecycle conflicts. Note however that
>   static @Bean methods will not be enhanced for scoping and AOP
>   semantics as mentioned above. This works out in BFPP cases, as they
>   are not typically referenced by other @Bean methods. As a reminder, a
>   WARN-level log message will be issued for any non-static @Bean methods
>   having a return type assignable to BeanFactoryPostProcessor.

In other words make sure that your `PropertiesFactoryBean` and `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` beans are declared as `static`, and it should work.